# Error while creating a site on arcGIS server manager

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

Everytime I try to create new site on ArcGIS server, it gives me this error.
"ERROR: Failed to create the site. Another administrative operation is currently accessing the store. Please try again later"
 Yet i'm unable to create my site on server[image]

Comment: are you using ArcGIS server 10.3 ? I have faced this problem with it, If yes the solution in may case is to format the machine and then install ArcGIS server again (let it be the first program  installed on your machine after format).

Comment: @Ahmadsaleh Yes its arcgis 10.3